# One API used by multiple clients with small variation in the flow

Tags: java, api-design, refactoring, polymorphism

I am working on refactoring codebase for a JAVA API thats used by multiple clients. Though the api provides the same overall functionality for all clients, actual flow changes a little bit between some clients. Two major examples are old clients using older version of dependency services and some functionality applies only to some clients. This is a read only API.

Our Current codebase has facade pattern and bunch of logic outside the facade as well. It also has a bunch of flags and depending on the flags we do things differently. The code started to become redundant between facades and it became harder to read and follow. Now I am trying to clean up the code and wondering whats the best way to approach this problem.

Here are the options I could think of

1. Abstract out common functionality into abstract classes (with an underlying interface ) and create concrete classes for each different flavor and override the methods that should be custom
2. Have one top-level method that handles the overall flow with some flags but keep the lines under flags very lean and clean.

I felt that facade pattern is probably not necessary here, but I am not sure. I prefer option 1 but wondering what solution will hold well for the constant change that our codebase goes through.

**EDIT**

Here is my current design
[image]

I am wondering if i should have one request builder and one request runner for each client (which will share the common code via abstract class) or should i have one common request builder and runner where some fields are used only by some clients depending on some flag. I am also wondering if I should use Intercepting Filter design pattern for building the request and building the response as there could be different pieces of logic involved in building the request and response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are optimising for. Are you:

1. striving to reduce collateral when performing a change?
2. striving to provide the full set of capabilities to all clients which can be opted in to?

---

In the first case you want to create separate instances of the *workflow*, one per client. This allows you to change what that workflow is without affecting any other client using your system.

On the plus side, this keeps changes confined to just the clients affected. You do not have to retest any of the other clients.

One the minus side, this means that a broad sweeping change requires you to change each variant, and it might not be an easily repeatable change as some workflows may have drifted significantly from each other over time.

You can still internally use common logic, but these need to be locked down, and treated as an operation. (Best with no nested control flow logic.)

---

In the second case you are providing a single set of behaviour, no customisation or specialisation for any client. In this case its a good idea to anoint one or two client implementations as *reference* implementations which are always kept working.

On the plus side, the teams for each and every client can use the new functionality as and when they choose.

On the other hand, every change will potentially break some or all of the non-reference clients. It also requires that these other teams are always monitoring and updating how they interact with your API.

---

Personally you will probably need to adopt both approaches. There will be cases where each individual circumstance of client/request/system state are best handled by separate self-contained specifications. There will be cases where a master definition with configuration is better.

---

A third option exists. Consider each piece of logic as pieces of lego.

Every flag/enumeration choose a piece from a set of possibilities all implementing the same interface.

Now instantiate the core logic piece. To do this it will require `X`, `Y`, `Z` logic pieces. Find those in the bag.

Wait `Y` needs `A` and `B`, grab those from the bag too.

Now its built, it can be run.

This is a happy median solution. Each piece is locked down. But the mix of pieces can be adjusted by the master controller. If you need to change something create a new piece and add it with some flag to the master controller.

---

**EDIT**

Flags are a decision point - a delayed if statement. This forces the implementation of the logic for the decision into various nooks and crannies in the code base.

This is unavoidable at an interchange point between disparate code bases. Such as the originating request would likely contain numerous flags etc.. describing intent, similarly for the response certain flags may be set to communicate state back to the client.

Within a codebase, it would be best to translate those flags directly into strategies, even if that resolution is hard-coded into named variables and passed down separately into the request handlers. Where the request handler needs to use that strategy it does not need to perform any logic, it simply calls the strategy.

---

Personally I would step back. What kinds of request are you receiving here?

- Are they identical requests being handled differently solely based on the client?
- Are they different requests being handled just based on that request?
- Are the requests being handled differently based on the state of those modules?

If the requests are being handled differently based on the client, I would take the road of publishing a separate API per client. Supplying all of the base functionality as a library that is configured by that endpoint. I would probably provide Builders, that serve the dual purpose of making it easier to configure end-points, but also verifying that that configuration has a corresponding set of tests at the library level.

If the requests are genuinely disparate and different from each other, but a given request is always processed in a given way, I would write independent handlers for each request type. The handler would be a single command function. Any common business operations would be factored out into their own commands and shared. If some portions of the handler logic are repetitive I would refactor those into support functions, but they would not be shared with any other handler.

If the requests are different based on the state of the modules I would rework the system completely. I would treat each module as an API passing the request to it. That module would then need to make its decision about how to fulfil the request. Be that return an answer, enrich and forward the request to another api, or pass it down to the processor, etc...

---

I'm getting the feeling that you have a heavy OO background. Considering how you have drawn out your architectural diagram, have you considered [Pipes and Filters Architecture](http://www.dossier-andreas.net/software_architecture/pipe_and_filter.html)?

This would probably help re-frame the problem. When a request is received the flags etc, represent an index into a table/map associated with a particular layout of pipes and filters. Instantiate the pipe (or using a previously instantiated copy) and pass the request into it.

It would allow you to balance:

- the nuances of the front-end, with each client/request specific nuance that changes behaviour
- have an explicit flow of processing for the request (as it exists on only one pipeline) which eases debugging later.
- have modular independent processing logic with clean independent tests
- provide a strategy for soft-configuring this processing later.

Comment: I had the same thought as your third option, but i didn't articulate it in my question. I am using dependency injection to achieve the same. Every independent functionality will be a dependency, how to put them together in an elegant way is what i am wondering about. I am planning to start simple and see how it works out.

Comment: The important part is to understand the kind of changes you want to perform later. All three of these solution work, but how well depends on what kinds of change they encounter.

Comment: I am wondering whats the best design to implement your option 3. I have updated the question with some more information. Can you please advice ?